# Spring and Jersey Client with session scoped bean

Tags: spring, jaxb, jersey, autowired

I would like to fill a spring session-scoped bean directly from the response of a webservice.

I obtain the proper response but it seems that jersey makes its own instance of the "Usuario" object without Spring being aware of it.

This is part of the validation class. It has "Usuario" autowired.

```
Client c = Client.create();
c.addFilter(...);

WebResource resource = c.resource(ws_url);

ClientResponse res = resource.
    type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
    .post(ClientResponse.class, req);

if (res.getStatus() == 200) {
    UsuarioAuthResponse u = res.getEntity(UsuarioAuthResponse.class);
    Usuario usuario = u.getDatos().getUsuario();
    return true;
}
```

"Usuario" is a spring session-scoped bean

```
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Usuario implements java.io.Serializable { ... }
```

Seems like getEntity makes its own instance of Usuario so the session data is not available through requests. I didn't found any examples of this on the web. Any help would be appreciated.

(* Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that Jersey will ask Spring "please give me the bean of class A"? Jersey does not know anything about Spring. What Jersey will do is to try to find the appropriate converter based on the response MIME type and given object class, that will create a new instance of this class and populate it with data from response. It can be XML (JAXB) or JSON (Jackson) or something else (custom converter).

What you actually need in this case is the ability of [load time weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) (read whole chapter 7.8). The basic idea is that you need to declare a special agent in your application server startup script, which will intersect the creation of all objects and make wiring based on Spring context for the particular application.

P.S. One face the same problem when he wants for example wire the beans created by ORM (Hibernate).